# Prestashop Webservice Api Login

Tags: php, apache, api, authentication, prestashop

Now, i have search whole web, find some topics but no solution.

My version is Prestashop 1.6.0.11,  PHP version 5.6.36, Enable CGI mode for PHP enabled/disabled doesn't matter

but the files are similar with latest version..

The problem is `domain.com/api` is not working with just submitting api key. it is just working by using `domain/api?ws_key=YOUR_KEY` or another version `apikey@domain.com` etc..

But i must use a web application which needs domain name and api key, so other solutions are not suitable for me. it is working at `localhost` by using just api, (same version and database and files) it means it is related with hosting but i couldn't find any error, made config files error log True, i try to do just view(get) . I asked them, but what is the question ? so no clear answer.

what can i do ?  any idea ? any way ?

htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

i read this , same.. https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/430312-presta-api-keep-asking-for-username-password-authentication-required/

Comment: any idea ?  about this situation.. nobody knows?

Answer (score 1):

Just create an .htaccess within webservice folder with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, with Prestashop 1.7.7.1